# Saving a url that changes as a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post so I'm sorry if I make any mistakes, I am trying my hardest. I have been looking for a couple of days now and I can't find a solution, I don't even know if it is possible. What I am trying to do is basic, I need to save a URL that changes as a JavaScript variable to call upon later on in a website. The URL is [http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aRandom) and it loads a random page. I want the variable to be the URL of the random page yet it is always just "http:// en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random". I thought I might need to load it somewhere else first for example in an iframe and then call the URL from there but it just stays as "http:// en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would I do some AJAX magic?

Comment: Eh, forget AJAX. It would be denied by an XSS policy. You have to do it with curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you linked redirects you when you access it. That means you have to request it before you get the actual random page you want.

One way you could try to do it is to load the random page in an iframe and check out the iframe's location.:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random';
iframe.name = "random";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console.log(window.frames['random'].location.href);
```

If you try that you will get a nasty sounding error, like this:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://run.jsbin.io" from accessing a frame with origin "http://en.m.wikipedia.org". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

The reason for it is because of the Same Origin policy which says that location is sensitive information and you're only allowed to access it if the iframe has the same protocol, domain and port as the page which is trying to access it.

The only solution now is to have a page on the server that makes a request to the random page, gets a response and grabs the url of that response. You can retrieve the url either through AJAX or you can simply integrate it in the page server side:

```
<html>
<body> This is my page and this is the random url:
<?php
  ... curl request to http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random from which you get the url
  echo $url;
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please give me the curl code as I am having difficulties?